# How to create launcher for java program in Ubuntu 17.10 (Gnome+Wayland)

Tags: java, launcher, gnome-shell, wayland, ubuntu-dock

**Since upgrading from Ubuntu 17.04 to Ubuntu 17.10 I have issues with launcher icons for java programs.**

For instance I use JPasswords password manager and have a .desktop file for it in /usr/share/applications/ and this file has specified also an icon. In Ubuntu 17.10 this desktop file still works, I can see the icon in the launcher and among all applications when click on Show Applications, but in case I launch it, it will create another icon with an icon taken from the jar file and I am not able to add it among favorites (make it permanent on the launcher). Further issue is the newly created icon has user non-friendly name displayed when cursor is hovered over it - for instance my JPasswords has name "org-jpws-front-PwsafeJ".
**Very same problem has also Oracle SQLDeveloper, so I assume any java app could be affected.**

Is there some fix or workaround for this?

Example of the issue can be seen on this screenshot:

[image]